Is there a way to set a timeout on JNDI connections for TomEE?
I've got a startup script that coordinates starting serveral processes, including TomEE (using openejb).  I want to be able to test the server status by first seeing if JNDI is available, using the following jndi.properties:
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http://0.0.0.0:8084/tomee/ejb
java.naming.security.principal=mysecurityprincipal
java.naming.security.credentials=mysecuritycredentials

While this works, it blocks for some time (~1min) on
  var ic = new InitialContext(props);

where props loads the properties above.  I'd like to be able to set a timeout (say, 5s) on the connection, to provide more immediate feedback in the script output, and then retry. However, I've not found any way to define the timeout. Is this possible?
